# Is there a way to let the compiler determine the namespace my classes, based on the directory structure of my project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, architecture, namespaces

In .NET and Visual Studio projects, the convention is to let the physical directory structure of your project resemble the namespace structure of the project. I totally agree with that, and every time I work on a project that violates this guideline, I have trouble finding types, because it's often unclear how to navigate the namespace hierarchy.

A problem I encounter however is that wrapping every class in a `namespace` is ***redundant***, when using this guideline. Furthermore, it makes it very hard (without commercial refactoring tools) to restructure the project structure later on, because every file needs to be changed.

I believe that moving classes to a different namespace should simply be a drag 'n drop of that file in another directory.

So how can we accomplish this? Is there a way to let the compiler (or any other tool) determine the namespace my classes (during compile time), based on the directory structure of my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can detect namespaces in code which do not match physical layout. Unfortunately Resharper is not cheap.

AFAIK the C# compiler has no knowledge of any relationship between namespace and physical location and therefore has no such options available.

IMHO this should be built into Visual Studio.

Comment: Does allow Resharper allow to change all mismatching namespaces with a simple click?

Comment: yes, go to the project/folder/solution you want to fix, right click and you can do it through the Refactor menu. I think the option is called "Adjust namespaces..."